# Recursive search through DOM to strip out innerText

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to recursively search through a DIV hierarchy and grab the innerText. I can only identify the parent by an ID but that is the only consistent piece of information. I know that within the children of that element there's a div with the text in it. What's the best way to do this recursively through all the children, and the children's children?

Here's a log of what I am getting:

```
Found text: .rLshyf,.BmP5tf{padding-top:56px;padding-bottom:56px}
Found text: .w1C3Le,.BmP5tf,.G5NbBd{padding-left:112px;padding-right:112px;}
Found text: .G5NbBd{padding-bottom:56px}
Found text: .ROYx{display:flex;justify-content:space-between}
Found text: .SkmBxc{width:988px;margin-right:68px}
Found text: .EURV7d{font-weight:500;margin-top:-8px}
Found text: .j8epzd{height:192px;margin-top:16px}
Found text: .UYT3jb{width:100%;height:2px;margin-top:24px;margin-bottom:24px;background-color:#303030}
Found text: .z24g9c{margin-top:32px}
Found text: .GsVE9b{float:right}
Found text: .MUxGbd{font-size:28px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;line-height:40px;padding-top:2px;margin-bottom:-2px}
Found text: .MUxGbd.ITUZi{font-size:40px;line-height:48px}
Found text: .lyLwlc{color:#202124}
Found text: .aLF0Z{text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden}
Found text: .MUxGbd.v0nnCb{font-size:32px;line-height:48px;padding-top:6px;margin-bottom:-6px;}
Found text: .lEBKkf{display:-webkit-box;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;overflow:hidden}
Found text: .L6lOSd{color:rgba(255,255,255,.5) !important}
Found text: .L6lOSd svg{fill:rgba(255,255,255,.5);height:24px;width:24px;vertical-align:middle;margin-left:8px}
Found text: .L6lOSd:hover{background-color:#303030;color:rgba(255,255,255,1) !important}
Found text: .L6lOSd:hover svg{fill:rgba(255,255,255,1)}
Found text: .L6lOSd:focus{background-color:#303030;color:rgba(255,255,255,1) !important}
Found text: .L6lOSd:focus svg{fill:rgba(255,255,255,1)}
Found text: .MUxGbd.gbj1yb{font-size:24px;line-height:32px;padding-top:0px;margin-bottom:-8px}
Found text: .WZ8Tjf{color:#70757A}
Found text: .WZ8Tjf a:visited{color:#acacac}
Found text: Is iPhone 8 waterproof?
Found text: The iPhone 8 and 8 Plus is not waterproof — no smartphone is. However, as you stated yourself, they do have an IP67 rating for dust and water-resistance.
Found text: Source: damage - Does the iPhone 8 have any sort of water resistance or ...
Found text: window.onUrlClick=function(a){var b=a.getAttribute("data-url");a=a.getAttribute("data-follow-up-query");b?window.parent.postMessage({url:{href:b}},"*"):a&&window.parent.postMessage({query:{queryText:a}},"*")};
Found text: const ENTER_KEYCODE = 13;const ENTER = 'Enter';
```

I don't understand why I am getting all of the inner styling text. How can I just grab the displayable text content?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: In my case the problem was that I was also getting text from style and script nodes.

Comment: I didn't see why this had to be downvoted unless maybe there's a duplicate question. The log is totally irrelevant and @LeeProbert was asking on how to do this not just requesting debugging help. I provided the answer before the debug log was added and now the log isn't really relevant. It would have made the question more confusing in my opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle recursion is by creating a recursive function so here is how you can go about it from the parent down the tree.

```js
function recurseEl(element) {
  if(element.childElementCount === 0) {
    element.textContent = '';
  } else {
    Array.from(element.children).forEach(child => {
      recurseEl(child);
    });
  }
}

function removeInnerText(elements) {
  recurseEl(element);
}

// Usage
const parentElement = document.getElementById('parent');
removeInnerText(parentElement);
```

This delegates the same recursive function down the tree provided there is still a child node in the tree. When it hits a leaf in the tree, it runs the replace function.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to log the content of the text nodes:

```
function logInnerText(elem) {
  if (elem.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && elem.nodeValue.trim())
    console.log(elem.parentNode.nodeName + ' contains ' + elem.nodeValue.trim())
  elem.childNodes.length && elem.childNodes.forEach(el => logInnerText(el))
}

logInnerText(document.getElementById('someId'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to remove all text nodes in an element:

```
function removeTextNodes(element){
    let i = 0;
    while (i<element.childNodes.length){
        let node = element.childNodes[i];
        if (node.nodeType==3){
            element.removeChild(node);
        }else if(node.nodeType==1){
            removeTextNodes(node);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```